# How to insert into values without duplicates?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, insert-update, insert-into

I created new table on another database which names "workers":

```
CREATE TABLE workers (
ID_WORKER int(11) NOT NULL,
FNAME varchar(20) NOT NULL,
LNAME varchar(20) NOT NULL,
WORKERS_GROUP varchar(20) NOT NULL,
POSITION varchar(50) NOT NULL,
CARD_NUMBER varchar(30) NOT NULL
)
```

Which 'ID_WORKER' column is set on AUTO_INCREMENT. Then first time i inserted only one record:

```
INSERT INTO workers (FNAME, LNAME, WORKERS_GROUP, POSITION, CARD_NUMBER) 
VALUES ('Paul', 'King', 'IT', 'Programmer', '');
```

But in the next times i tried insert on another methods (which i'll describe what i've tried) and i had some duplicates.

**What i've tried?**

I've tried insert into without duplicates at least 3 methods yet:

1) By INSERT IGNORE INTO:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO workers (FNAME, LNAME, WORKERS_GROUP, POSITION, CARD_NUMBER)
```

2) By REPLACE INTO:

```
REPLACE INTO workers (FNAME, LNAME, WORKERS_GROUP, POSITION, CARD_NUMBER) 
VALUES ('Paul', 'King', 'IT', 'Programmer', '');
```

3) By INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO workers (FNAME, LNAME, WORKERS_GROUP, POSITION, CARD_NUMBER) 
VALUES ('Paul', 'King', 'IT', 'Programmer', '') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FNAME = 'Paul' AND LNAME = 'King' AND WORKERS_GROUP = 'IT' AND POSITION = 'Programmer' AND CARD_NUMBER = ''
```

And none of them didn't work. I have no idea or clue where can I find them. Any ideas thx for any help.

**EDIT**

As for as duplicates are concerned can be all of them, but in that case the worker with the same `FNAME, LNAME` can be in the same `WORKER_GROUP` be he/she has to have another `POSITION` and `CARD_NUMBER`.

Comment: In your `CREATE TABLE` script, there is no `AUTO_INCREMENT` as you stated.

Comment: You have nothing defined in your table definition that would stop you inserting `'Paul', 'King', 'IT', 'Programmer', ''` 1000's of times.

Comment: even if the id_worker is an auto_increment field, that wouldn't avoid what @RiggsFolly is talking about. 1000 Pauls with just a different id. Isn't that a duplicate?

Comment: You can use [INSERT IGNORE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/) but you have to create a unique index on the combination of `FNAME, LNAME, WORKERS_GROUP, POSITION, CARD_NUMBER`.

Comment: I am really not sure if you want duplicates or not?? Judging by your INSERT..DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE example you are trying to create Duplicates

Comment: I thought you meant duplicated `ID_WORKER`. I wouldn't check for duplicated workers. What if you have 2 peoples having the same firstname and name working in the same group at the same position. This can be rare, but this **may** happen

Comment: @Cid I mean that when i insert the same value of all of them `(FNAME, LNAME, WORKERS_GROUP, POSITION, CARD_NUMBER)` i thought it shouldn't duplicate that data regardless of `ID_WORKER`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i was trying avoid dupplicates (not create duplicates) INSERT..DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE when i read about this mysql command.

Comment: So which columns do you consider should not be duplicated please

Comment: @Cid I modified ID_WORKER column to AUTO_INCREMENT after creating that table.

Comment: @RiggsFolly can be all of them, But in that case the worker with the same FNAME, LNAME can be in the same WORKER_GROUP be he/she has have another position and card number. Will it be helpful enough? :)

Comment: So you will have to do as @KIKOSoftware suggested above and create a unique index on whichever columns make sense to you and your requirement

Comment: Ok. I've made that as @KIKOSoftware suggested and it works. Thx a lot mate. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO workers (FNAME, LNAME, WORKERS_GROUP, POSITION, CARD_NUMBER)
SELECT DISTINCT w1.FNAME, w1.LNAME, w1.WORKERS_GROUP, w1.POSITION, w1.CARD_NUMBER
FROM workers w1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM workers w2
                  WHERE w2.FNAME = w1.FNAME
                    AND w2.LNAME= w1.LNAME
                    AND w2.WORKERS_GROUP= w1.WORKERS_GROUP
                    AND w2.POSITION = w1.POSITION
                    AND s2.CARD_NUMBER = w1.CARD_NUMBER)
```

Comment: Really not sure what you are suggesting here? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Comment: it prevents the duplication of new row

Comment: @kishan can you please tell me what kind of `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1` in your code is? Is it about ID_Worker? I understand that alias w1 and w2 appeal to 1 table workers, right?

Comment: @kishan but by the way i have to insert values. Not only select.

Comment: @kishan you can replace *SELECT DISTINCT w1.FNAME, w1.LNAME, w1.WORKERS_GROUP, w1.POSITION, w1.CARD_NUMBER
FROM workers w1* with yours desired values  like  *SELECT FNAME, LNAME, WORKERS_GROUP, POSITION, CARD_NUMBER FROM ( SELECT  'Paul' as FNAME, 'King' AS LNAME, 'IT' AS WORKERS_GROUP, 'Programmer' AS POSITION, '' AS CARD_NUMBER  ) AS w1*